# What's the style from these "Humble Bundle Monthly" illustrations?

Tags: illustration, style-identification

I'm falling in love with humble bundle monthly illustration that used on their video and background image on their website. Unfortunately it had changed already :( so you can't look at their website (humblebundle.com),  But I have some example from the images:

https://youtu.be/rkOfIpq5YRM

[image: http://blackmannrobin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Humble-Monthly-Bundle-Art-2.png]

[image: http://blackmannrobin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Humble-Monthly-Bundle-Art-1.jpg]

Well, I already try low poly (even low poly doesn't look exactly like that, but just because I see some edge like triangle :v ) and cartoon (because of the character) but can't meet exactly what I want.

What I want to know is what kind of genre those illustration? and Are there some online resource that I can visit to learn creating something like that?

Comment: Hi there! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2930) for style identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Thanks luciano, edited , let me know if it's still miss to the guideline

Comment: I keep seeing Road Runner in the first picture.

Answer (score 1):

These are **vector illustrations**, most likely created using Adobe Illustrator and finished off in Adobe Photoshop. By the look of it the illustrator has used a Wacom pen tablet and a number of vector art brushes to create a soft, painterly effect. These illustrations work because of the subtle, clever use of colour and transparency effects. That, and the layouts themselves are very well considered and beautifully balanced.

There are heaps of tutorials online that will give you a good grounding in how to use Illustrator, but to create something like this you will also need to understand what makes a good composition, and this isn't as simple as following a set of instructions.

I would suggest you find a photo you really love, placing it in Illustrator (locked it on a *template layer*) and then recreate it in vectors over the top. Straight up trial and error – that's how I taught myself Illustrator.

Who knows you might even discover your own illustrative style in the process.

Comment: but are you sure it's just vector illustration? or we can call it cartoon or flat also?

Comment: I don't think there's really a specific name for it. It's definitely inspired by old cartoons like Looney Tunes (check out the shapes in that desert)

Comment: I dont see any trace of usinga  wacom. theres nothing that telltale that makes it visible

Comment: @joojaa you think the brushstroke are actual brushstrokes, scanned in and rasterised?

Comment: @Alex its hard to say, vector apps nowdays have natural media strokes so it would be a few layers of those. Second input like that can be achieved with mouse ive done it on ocasions when I havent got a wacom. But in general its hard to say what if anything was used there are lots of ways. So I wouldnt speculate over the input device too much. Same applies to use of illustrator in general, one could paint by mask in any pixel manipulator for same effect.

Comment: I think they also use transparency to get subtle differences in tone, and layer overlay effects. Experimentation is key.